# Android: File Not Found Exception

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to program a simple todo app for my android phone. Ive gotten far enough that I would like to save these strings that I input. However, every time I try to write the data I get a file not found exception. Here is the code I use in my onCreate method to instantiate the File.

```
File path = getFilesDir();
File itemFile = new File(path,"Todo_File.txt");
```

I then have two methods, one to write to the File, and the other to read from it. They look like this:`

```
public void readItems() {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Todo_File.txt"));
        while(reader.readLine()!=null){
            items.add(reader.readLine());
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and

```
public void writeItems() {
    try{
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Todo_File.txt"));
        for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
            writer.write(items.get(i));
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

items is a stringArray which holds the strings that were input. Every time that I try to write or read the files I get the following exception:

W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Todo_File.txt (No such file or directory)

I don't understand why Android Studio cant find the file that I created, can anyone help?

Comment: you should use the `File itemFile` you defined

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Indeed. FileWriter will use a full path. Not only a file name. So use itemFile.getAbsolutePath().

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do File-IO in Android is using the context-relevant IO-methods.

To **write** a file, use the following code. Details about the different file-modes are available [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("Todo_File.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

To **read** a file, use this:

```
FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("Todo_File.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a file "Todo_File.txt".

Where have you kept this file? 
Are you keeping it as a resource file in the "res/raw" directory of your app or it is lying somewhere in the phone storage?

Here you can get some idea of types of the storage

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112951/two-types-of-internal-storage-what-is-the-difference

Mostly likely I guess you need to correct the path of this file.
here are the way to get the "/storage/sdcard0/" path

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: I am attempting to place it in the phone's internal memory. Do the first two lines of code not accomplish that?

Comment: You just need to provide the full path. For example, if it's in Download directory then use - "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()//Download//Todo_File.txt"

Comment: Also, I saw you are trying to write the file as well so you need to take Write permission as well to write the file with correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined

```java
File path = getFilesDir();  
File itemFile = new File(path,"Todo_File.txt");
```

you can do:

```java
public void readItems() {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(itemFile));
        while(reader.readLine()!=null){
            items.add(reader.readLine());
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```java
public void writeItems() {
    try{
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(itemFile));
        for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
            writer.write(items.get(i));
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually create the file before you write to it. You should do something like this:

```
File path = getFilesDir();  
File itemFile = new File(path,"Todo_File.txt");

if (!path.exists()) {
     path.mkdirs();
}
```

What you have done is simply tried to read from the file. The fact that you get the error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Todo_File.txt (No such file or directory)
```

Is an indication that the file you want to write to hasn't been created, and I don't see you creating the file anywhere.

If you are using an emulator, you need to make sure that you have an SDK card set up on your device, and then do:

```
File itemFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Todo_File.txt");

if (!path.exists()) {
     path.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: so using the device monitor, I went in to the emulated phone's files and the directory specified by the File doesn't exist, even after adding your code. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are using an emulator, you are going to want to set up your device to have an SD Card, and then write to the external storage. See my update.